# firefox "padding" its window on debian 11 - grabbing clicks meant for other overlapping windows

Tags: gnome, firefox, window

Since some "apt-get **dist**upgrade" ~ 1/2 a year ago, firefox "grabs" mouse clicks and keys pressed more than a dozen pixels **outside** its window border. That's nastily disturbing my work, because I'm used to working with overlapping windows. I might type into a Gnome terminal while looking at the browser overlapping most of the Gnome terminal. Before THAT upgrade it was a few pixels - no problem. Now it's more than a line height in terminal, so it's easy to unintentionally type/click into firefox instead of terminal.

Where can this "padding" be configured? I guess each program may have its own "padding", because I can see windows without (chromium e.g.), a few pixels (many have a few pixels, so I guess this is the default in gnome) and firefox with an insane amount of pixels around it.

I am using Gnome **on Debian 11**.

Any help appreciated.

---edit1:
I've made some little changes to the original question above and marked them **bold**

Gnome-shell --version   says:  GNOME Shell 3.38.6

In order to easily use overlapping windows I use "focus follows mouse"; in gnome-tweaks it reads: Window Focus: Focus on Hover.

--edit2:
Just tried in a fresh install of debian11.3 on a virtual machine. Didn't change any defaults, just did an "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade", rebooted and started terminal and firefox.

This time we have the default Window Focus: Click to Focus - The same behaviour happens. To make clear what I'm talking about, I add some screenshots. Sorry, they are a bit huge, but I wanted to show the exact cursor position:

Click mouse on background window - it is foregrounded as expected:

[image: Click mouse on background window]

[image: Window comes to foreground as expected]

But if cursor is slightly nearer to firefox window, firefox window comes to foreground instead (cursor style changes when firefox "grabs" it):

[image: Cursor "too close" to firefox window]

[image: Firefox "grabbed" the cursor]

---edit3:
Meanwhile I've tested with the same fresh install on a virtual machine, but without first "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade". It's all the same.

Then I tried Libreoffice (Thank you Eduardo for this idea), it behaves exactly like gnome-terminal - mouse hits the window just a few pixels outside the window.

Tried Ubuntu-22.04.1 - Firefox, Gnome-terminal and Libreoffice behave just like on debian11.

Now I tried Chromium - here OS versions behave differently:

- on my debian11 Notebook in everyday use (Focus on Hover): you have to hit the border exactly
- on debian virtual machine fresh install (Focus on Click): behaves bad like firefox. Setting Focus on Hover makes no difference.
- on debian virtual machine fresh install + "apt-get update&& apt-get dist-upgrade", (Focus on Click): behaves just as bad
- on ubuntu-22.04.1 virtual machine fresh install (Focus on Clock): behaves like gnome-terminal - just a few pixels

@cas: I guess this behaviour originates from the trend to minimize border, while maintaining the possibility to easily hit the border to manipulate window width/height. That's a good idea, imho.

However, I'd like to be able to adjust it a bit, but :-( didn't find a way to do that yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what version of Gnome you are using and what operating system. Also tell us what kind of mouse policy you are using. Is it "click to focus" or "focus under mouse" or something else? Do you need to click on a window to make it take focus, or is putting your mouse over it enough?

Comment: I've never seen anything like the behaviour you describe in many years of using Firefox on Debian (although I don't use Gnome) and on other systems.  Is it, perhaps, some kind of accessibility option (e.g. to implement a "near enough is good enough" feature for people who have difficulty with precisely controlling a mouse or other pointer device)? That's the only valid reason I can think of for what otherwise sounds like a bug.  So, maybe look in gnome's accessibility settings.

Comment: Is Firefox the only application "overreaching"? Can you test in the fresh install with Libreoffice and maybe another program, say `ev`?